# How to keep track of revisions?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, versioning, revision-history

I am trying to design my database and I want to have the ability to keep a track of history of changes.

I will have a table that will have all the nutritional facts of an food. When a user makes changes to the item(say changes calories from 100 to 200). I want to make that as a new revision.

That way a person who comes along can see that it was original 100 calories and then was updated to 200 calories. I guess this would be alot like how stack does it now where you can see what has been edited.

I am wondering what is the best way to do this? I am using sql server and nhibernate.

I was thinking of have another column or something that would be revision number. Then every-time a revision is made the number is incremented. Is this a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NHibernate.Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers) helps you with that.

Comment: Does it have to be separate audit tables. I just find it weird with audit tables. I am not really auditing anything. So don't know if I really need a separate table. I will read more into this.

Comment: Yes it has to be seperate audit tables. If it's not "auditing" you're looking for but rather part of your business rules, then Envers is probably not for you. Perhaps you can solve it in your domain model rather than some technical solution then?

Comment: Basically I am looking for something that I can show different revisions of values that changed. Nothing for auditing purposes. So I guess just a revision  number in the same table might do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do as you've written, add another revision number.

Another approach would be adding a timestamp and use that as history. Every time an item is updated you add a row with the current values and the current timestamp.

Comment: hmm timestamp might be good as the one thing I am kinda worried of is incrementing the revision number. What happens if 2 people update at the same time how to make sure that the number is incremented correctly(not both try to increment the number to 2)

Comment: @chobo2 Sql server should already take car of that. If you do `update nutritions set calories = 200, revision = revision + 1, ...`

Comment: yes but don't I have to get what is in revision. Meaning I would have to let nhibernate get the last revision number and store it and then add 1 to it?

Comment: @chobo2 If you say `revision = revision + 1`, your database does the increment. I'm not familiar with NHibernate, but from the documentation [Custom SQL for create, update and delete](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-cud) I've seen, you can tell NHibernate to use a custom update SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally use some form of audit table(s) to handle this. What we do where I currently work is have all our audit tables under an audit schema, and we have an audit table for every that we wish to track revisions for. We don't use NHibernate, so we simply utilise triggers to ensure that every update to a given row is recorded in the audit table along with a timestamp and user id so you can get some context and order to the way in which the revisions were made.

It seems like [it is difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583583/how-to-tell-nhibernate-that-a-trigger-updates-another-table) using triggers with NHibernate, but you could use something like NHibernate interceptors or events as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859017/685760). I'd say triggers would be preferable to relying on your code, but if this is the only way to go with NHibernate, then maybe it is worth a look.

Lastly, I've seen it mentioned that you can use SQL Servers native [audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or trace capabilities. I've never used this myself, but do remember some post on SO suggesting that this replaced the need for creating your own manual audit tables and associated triggers. It seems to do what you want as illustrated by this quote from the link above;

> The auditing of activity of users, roles, or groups on database
>   objects can be restricted down to the table level. That is, you can
>   target SQL Server Audit to track specific activities of a user or
>   users down to the individual table level. For example, SQL Server
>   Audit allows a record to be made of all the UPDATEs to the Payroll
>   table by DBO.

To me that sounds more like a true audit rather than just a revision history, but maybe someone with more experience in this area could comment on its feasibility to be used for revision tracking. Of course, you'd have to see what effect it had on NHibernate also.